# How do I fix this type mismatch lint error on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, lint, code-inspection

The annotation doesn't say clearly what to do to solve the problem:

> **Name**
>
> protected method void **onMeasure**(***int*** **widthMeasureSpec**, ***int*** **heightMeasureSpec**)
>
> **Problem**
>
> synopsis      Value must be ≥ 0 and ≤ 1073741823

This is the code that lint complaining about:

```
private int mMaxHeight = WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE;

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    try {
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (mMaxHeight != WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE
                && heightSize > mMaxHeight) {
            heightSize = mMaxHeight;
        }
        // First parameter of MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec has lint error
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSize, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        //heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(R.dimen.something, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        getLayoutParams().height = heightSize;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MaxHeightListView", "Error forcing height", e);

    } finally {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

`heightSize` is just an int value, also tried with a resource dimension (R.dimen.something), but the issue persists.

Comment: You have private int mMaxHeight = WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE; and then in your if statmenet you said mMaxHeight != WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE which is is equal to that and there is no else so your automatically jumping out of the if statement.

Comment: @AdamGardner Initializing `WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY - 1` gets rid of the error, thanks.

Comment: @AdamGardner Maybe `WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE = MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED` is even better.